# How can I access wireless Internet from far away?

Tags: windows-xp, networking, wireless-networking, internet-connection

I don't have regular access to DSL. My neighbor has. He is willing to get his signal wirelessly, but it's 835ft and lots of trees.

Could I use 300ft of ethernet cable to get me through the trees to an antenna with a USB connection? If I do would I have to go back to a USB connection before I plug it into my computer? Or is the whole thing impossible?

I don't want to cut 300 ft of trees.

Comment: +1 for "I don't want to cut 300 ft of trees".

Comment: You might be able to run an ethernet line 300 ft to a wireless access point, and have that AP talk to another AP a few hundred feet away, but if there's a reasonable budget, I'd google up "ethernet extender" -- there's a model at Amazon that runs under $300 and claims to have a 1 km range over a single pair of wires (phone wiring, ethernet cable, etc.)

Comment: See: http://superuser.com/questions/186247/wirelessly-linking-buildings-1-000-ft-apart  http://superuser.com/questions/298164/connecting-networks-for-two-buildings  http://superuser.com/questions/227056/how-can-i-beam-my-wifi-signal-across-the-street http://superuser.com/questions/293764/extend-internet-connection

Comment: at almost 1000 ft you will need some heavy duty equipment for a point to point bridge. If you have the cash these WILL do what you want but like anything you have to pay: http://www.ruckuswireless.com/products/zoneflex-outdoor/7731

Answer (score 3):

If there is power every 300ft, you could use three 300ft lengths of Ethernet cable and two switches to bridge the gap, assuming you own all the land between your place and your neighbor's (I believe 300ft is within the retransmission limits-- The last time I did this I was using lengths of 250ft of cable). Obviously you need to sufficiently waterproof and prepare the cabling and switches to withstand the outdoor elements.

You cannot attach a USB plug to either end of a 300ft Ethernet cable and use it as a long USB cable.

The other option would be to use high-gain directional antennas with suitable WiFi access points.

Comment: Looks like I'm gonna have to cut some trees to get a clear line of sight. I don't know how to connect a ethernet cable to a cantenna and the 400 cable is too expensive

Answer (score 3):

You will be amazed at how far a home brew antenna will work(see links):

> [www.turnpoint.net/wireless/has.html](http://www.turnpoint.net/wireless/has.html)
>
> [www.dxzone.com/catalog/Antennas/WiFi/](http://www.dxzone.com/catalog/Antennas/WiFi/)